# The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String' in flutter for shared prefrances

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

so I am using shared preferences in a flutter app and I get this error :
**The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'**
and here is the code:

```
if (result != null) {
      SharedPreferenceHelper().saveUserEmail(userDetails.email);
    }
```

the error is **userDetils.email** can someone pls help
[A picture of what it shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEOlZ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking into the image posted the line 30 declaration states that:

```
User? userDetails = result.user;// Which potentially means that variable userDetails could be null
```

Where as the class User details are not shared but peaking into the issue I am pretty sure the class `User` has a email parameter whose declaration is as includes it's datatype as `String? email` something like this with prefix of `final` or `late`.

In this case what happens is that you have nested level of nullity for accessing `email` variable out of `userDetails` object.
Which means:

```
Case 1=> userDetails is null and email is null.
Case 2=> userDetails is not null and email is null.
Case 3=> userDetails is not null and email is not null.

Meaning both `userDetails` and `email` have a datatype of which defines them to be null at compile time.
```

Since dart is statically typed language so you need to add in `!` after each variable whose datatype is nullable at compile time to allow dart know that the variable has data in it and was assigned a value sometime later in run time.

So to fix this what you need to do is that replace the line below with line 33:

```
SharedPreferenceHelper().saveUserEmail(userdetails!.email ?? "Some default email");
// if you never want to save null as email pref else use the one below
SharedPreferenceHelper().saveUserEmail(userdetails!.email.toString());
```

Answer (score 4):

Those are two different types. You need to coerce String? to String either by the null coercion operator: `userDetails.email!` or by giving it a default value if it's null: `userDetails.email ?? ''`

Answer (score 0):

It is sound null safety problem
**String?** means Whatever variable assigned to Stirng? type it can be null or null value is available
,so make sure to check it null or not by providing **userDetils.email??**  this means userDetils.email is null  or not